Order columns in a matrix
I have a matrix mat. I would like to re-order the columns, using column name:
mat <-matrix(1:12,3)
colnames(mat) <-  c("I to I",   "I to II",  "I to III", "I to IV")  

ordered_mat <- cbind(mat[,"I to IV"],mat[,"I to II"],mat[,"I to I"],mat[,"I to III"])

This works, however, the column name disappeared and now I just have V1,V2...,V4, instead. Is there a better way to do this, while preserving the column names?

Subsetting a single column of a matrix will give you a vector.
mat[,"I to IV"]
#> [1] 10 11 12

You can add drop = FALSE to retain the matrix form.
mat[,"I to IV", drop = FALSE]
#>      I to IV
#> [1,]      10
#> [2,]      11
#> [3,]      12

So in your example you would
mat <-matrix(1:12,3)
colnames(mat) <-  c("I to I",   "I to II",  "I to III", "I to IV")  

ordered_mat <- cbind(mat[,"I to IV", drop = FALSE],mat[,"I to II", drop = FALSE],mat[,"I to I", drop = FALSE],mat[,"I to III", drop = FALSE])
ordered_mat
#>      I to IV I to II I to I I to III
#> [1,]      10       4      1        7
#> [2,]      11       5      2        8
#> [3,]      12       6      3        9

